# React router not working with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router

I have the following setup:

```
<div>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={NewCustomerContainer} />
        <Route path="/newCustomer" component={NewCustomerContainer} />
        <Route path="/search" component={SearchPageContainer} />
        <Route path="/network" component={NetworkContainer} />
        <Route path="/network/:id" component={NetworkContainer} ></Route>
    </Router>
</div>
```

The route `http://localhost:8100/network` works fine. The route `http://localhost:8100/network/abc123` does not with a 404 error appearing in my console. Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<div>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={NewCustomerContainer} />
        <Route path="/newCustomer" component={NewCustomerContainer} />
        <Route path="/search" component={SearchPageContainer} />
        <Route path="/network" component={NetworkMetaContainer}>
            <Route path="/:id" component={NetworkContainer}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
</div>
```

You forgot to nest the the '/id' inside the network Route.
React Router allows for nested routing by placing Routes inside other Routes... If you have all network/id stuff inside the network and the network renders its children then this will work correctly.

The new NetworkMetaContainer will need to be built that has a simple render children... or if you want you can perhaps have a `<IndexRoute />` inside the network Route, but either way the NetworkMetaContainer thing must be just the outer wrapper (maybe it'll have the different tabs or links or possibilities inside the Network)?

Comment: This + changing `http://localhost:8100/network/abc123` -> `http://localhost:8100/networkabc123` worked a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: I had to redeclare for it to work on my end; `<Route path="/jobs" component={Job} >
              <Route path="/jobs/:jobTab" component={Job} />
            </Route>`

Answer (score 27):

Something else to try is to add a

```
<base href="/">
```

tag inside the head tags of your base HTML page.

Comment: Oh, wow. This actually worked for me. Thanks! Why does it work though?

Comment: it works for me too! in my case it works because if the base url is not set, it will try to load the resource files using the defined path (the path having params) as the base url..

Comment: Works for me using `react-router-dom` v5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

try to add prop `exact={true}` inside `Route` component

```
<div>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={NewCustomerContainer} />
        <Route path="/newCustomer" component={NewCustomerContainer} />
        <Route path="/search" component={SearchPageContainer} />
        <Route path="/network" exact={true} component={NetworkContainer} />
        <Route path="/network/:id" exact={true} component={NetworkContainer} ></Route>
    </Router>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you are using react-router-dom https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components

Put your more specific route **before** the other:

```
<Route path="/posts/:id" exact>
  <Post />
</Route>
<Route path="/posts">
  <Posts />
</Route>
```

> Note how these two routes are ordered. The more specific
> path="/contact/:id" comes before path="/contact" so that route will
> render when viewing an individual contact

Answer (score 0):

Base href didn't work for me. This did though:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path={['/network/:id', '/network']} component={NetworkContainer} />
</Router>
```